# What's faster: instanceof or isInstance?

Tags: java, jvm, instanceof

Design questions aside, what performs faster on modern JVMs?

```
foo instanceof Bar
```

or

```
Bar.class.isInstance(foo)
```

Why?

Comment: #1.  It's built into the language.  You're not going to get better than that.

Comment: It almost never matters what's faster.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not trying to do better, I'm just curious which operation is faster.

Comment: It's practically impossible to tell without measuring. `Class.isInstanceOf()` is an intrinsic method in OpenJDK (and possibly in every modern VM), meaning that it's as fast as possible. `instanceof` on the other hand has its own bytecode operation, so it can potentially be even faster. How calls to each is optimised by Hotspot is another matter.

Comment: As for it not being a duplicate, the question may be different, but the answer is the same. If you want benchmark data, the most reliable thing is to write your own [microbenchmark](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), as any published benchmark data can easily be obsolete or not apply to your specific environment.

Comment: `Class.isInstance` is JVM intrinsic. It is compiled to exactly the same sequence as `instanceof` does (the proof from HotSpot source code: [1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b5b3db42efca/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l3568), [2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b5b3db42efca/src/share/vm/opto/graphKit.cpp#l2840)). That is, they both are equal in terms of performance.

Comment: @apangin That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Class.isInstance` is JVM intrinsic. It is compiled to exactly the same sequence as instanceof does (the proof from HotSpot source code: [1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b5b3db42efca/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l3568), [2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b5b3db42efca/src/share/vm/opto/graphKit.cpp#l2840)). That is, they both are equal in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

`foo instanceof Bar` should be faster.

You can use `Bar.class.isInstance(foo)` if it's not clear at compile time which class you have.

consider the following:

```
void test(Object o1, Object o2) {
   o1.getClass().isInstance(o2);
}
```

In this exsample the JVM decides at runtime which class calls the method.
With `instanceof` this is not possible.

So if you know the class at compile time you should use `instanceof`